# Confused about side effects / ContinueAfter

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a scenario in which I download parent entities from an api and save them to  a database. I then want, once all of the parents have been saved, to download and save their children.

I've seen (or misunderstood) some comments about how this is a side-effect as I will not be passing the result of the parent save operation to the save children operation. I simply want to begin it when the parents are saved.

Could someone explain to me the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
Observable
    .Create<int>(o =>
    {
        var parentIds = new int?[] { null };
        return
            Observable
                .While(
                    () => parentIds.Any(),
                    parentIds
                        .ToObservable()
                        .Select(parentId => Save(parentId)))
                        .Finally(() => { /* update `parentIds` here with next level */ })
                .Subscribe(o);
    })
    .Subscribe(x => { });
```

This is effectively doing a breadth-first traversal of all of the entities, saving them as it goes, but outputting a single observable that you can subscribe to.